# Angular 4 - Populate form with JSON data is not working

Tags: json, angular, forms, typescript

I have to edit data from a client. I have a form, in which I click on a button and redirects to a Form, in I want it to display the data of that client that I've just clicked. 
Thing is, the form builder does not work when I try to associate each key to its value.

However, if I write down the name myself, like, hardcoded, the form builder works like a charm!.

*edit-component.ts*

```
import { FuncionForm } from './../../interfaces/funcion_form';
import { FuncionService } from './../../services/funcion.service';
import { Combobox } from './../../interfaces/combobox';
import { ComboboxService } from './../../services/combobox.service';
import { Formulario } from './../../interfaces/formulario';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { SharedService } from './../../services/shared-service.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Funcion } from '../../interfaces/funcion';
import {
  FormGroup,
  Validators,
  FormBuilder,
  FormControl,
  FormsModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule
} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
selector: 'app-editar-funcion',
templateUrl: './editar-funcion.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./editar-funcion.component.css']
})
export class EditarFuncionComponent implements OnInit {

funcionCD:                number;
dadosFormulario :         FuncionForm;
funcionFormGroup:         FormGroup;
comboboxProfisArray :     Combobox;
comboboxAgrupProfArray :  Combobox;
comboboxAgrupCategArray : Combobox;
comboboxNacionArray :     Combobox;
myForm :                  FormGroup;  

 constructor(private sharedService : SharedService,
          private funcionService : FuncionService,
          private funcionFormBuilder: FormBuilder,
          private comboboxService: ComboboxService) 
 {}

ngOnInit() { 

this.sharedService.currentClientCD.subscribe(message => this.funcionCD = message); // Service to get the client ID

this.funcionService.GetDadosCliente(this.funcionCD).subscribe(
  (res:FuncionForm) => {
    this.dadosFormulario = res; // Interface to define a client


// This works!
this.myForm = new FormGroup({ 
  nome :          new FormControl("A name"),
  dt_nasc :       new FormControl("1998-02-25"),
  sexo :          new FormControl("0"),
  cd_nacion :     new FormControl("PT"),
  cd_agrup_prof : new FormControl("M"),
  cd_profis :     new FormControl("M"),
  cd_categ :      new FormControl("M"),
  loc_trab :      new FormControl("A company") 
  // This works!

  /* This doesn't!
 this.myForm = new FormGroup({ 
  nome :          new FormControl(this.dadosFormulario[0].nome),
  dt_nasc :       new FormControl(this.dadosFormulario[0].dt_nasc),
  sexo :          new FormControl(this.dadosFormulario[0].sexo),
  cd_nacion :     new FormControl(this.dadosFormulario[0].cd_nacion),
  cd_agrup_prof : new FormControl(this.dadosFormulario[0].cd_agrup_prof),
  cd_profis :     new FormControl(this.dadosFormulario[0].cd_profis),
  cd_categ :      new FormControl(this.dadosFormulario[0].cd_categ),
  loc_trab :      new FormControl(this.dadosFormulario[0].loc_trab) 
   */

 })      
}
```

*edit-component.html*

```
<div class="container">
 <h1>Editar dados do funcionário</h1>
 <hr>
 <div class="card">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3" id="col-img">
        <img src="/img/1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9" id="col-dados">
      <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" [formGroup]="myForm">

      <!-- 
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label class="col-md-12 col-form-label">Local de trabalho</label>
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <input formControlName="loc_trab" type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
      -->
        <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-md-12 col-form-label">Nome</label>
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <input formControlName="nome" type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-md-12 col-form-label">Data de nascimento</label>
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <input formControlName="dt_nasc" type="date" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
          <label class="col-md-12 col-form-label">Género</label>
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <select formControlName="sexo" type="text" class="form-control">
              <option value="0">Masculino</option>
              <option value="1">Feminino</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
          <label class="col-md-12 col-form-label">Nacionalidade</label>
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <select formControlName="cd_nacion" type="text" class="form-control">
              <option *ngFor="let row of comboboxNacionArray" value="{{ row.cd }}">{{ row.nome }}</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
          <label class="col-md-12 col-form-label">Agrupamento Profissional</label>
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <select formControlName="cd_agrup_prof" type="text" class="form-control">
              <option *ngFor="let row of comboboxAgrupProfArray" value="{{ row.cd }}">{{ row.nome }}</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
          <label class="col-md-12 col-form-label">Profissão</label>
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <select formControlName="cd_profis" type="text" class="form-control">
              <option *ngFor="let row of comboboxProfisArray" value="{{ row.cd }}">{{ row.nome }}</option>
            </select>
          </div>  
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
          <label class="col-md-12 col-form-label">Categoria Profissional</label>
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <select formControlName="cd_categ" type="text" class="form-control">
              <option *ngFor="let row of comboboxAgrupCategArray" value="{{ row.cd }}">{{ row.nome }}</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
          <label class="col-md-12 col-form-label">Local de trabalho</label>
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <input formControlName="loc_trab" type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-top: 15px;">
              <button style="border-radius: 50px; float:right;" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submeter</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*Some screnshots*

[Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zbjfv.png)

[Not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKgce.png)

I've searched everywhere and couldn't find a solution.
All help is apreciated!

PS: the JSON data comes like this. Thats why the "0" in **this.dadosFormulario[0]**

```
[
  {
    "nome": "MY NAME",
    "dt_nasc": "1978-05-26T00:00:00",
    "sexo": "0",
    "cd_nacion": "2", 
    "cd_agrup_prof": null,
    "cd_profis": "1",
    "cd_categ": "TS",
    "loc_trab": ""
   }
 ]
```

Comment: I think that's the problem is that myForm has no value at first. You can enclosed your form in a < div *ngIf="myForm">....< /div>. So add to your < div ***ngIf="myForm"** class="col-md-9" id="col-dados">...< /div>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To pre-populate data there are two methods of FormGroup instance. `setValue()` & `patchValue()`. After you receive the response from the server just set/patch the values using one of these methods `setValue()` and `patchValue()` both sets the value in `form control` of `FormGroup`.  `setValue()` sets the value for each and every form control of FormGroup. you cannot omit any form control in `setValue()` but if you want to assign only few form controls of FormGroup then you can use `patchValue().`

**Modified Code**

```
ngOnInit() { 
    this.initializeForm();
    this.sharedService.currentClientCD.subscribe(message => this.funcionCD = message); // Service to get the client ID

    this.funcionService.GetDadosCliente(this.funcionCD).subscribe(
      (res:FuncionForm) => {
        this.dadosFormulario = res; // Interface to define a client

    this.myForm.setValue(
     {

        nome :      this.dadosFormulario[0].nome,
        dt_nasc :      this.dadosFormulario[0].dt_nasc,
        sexo :         this.dadosFormulario[0].sexo,
        cd_nacion :     this.dadosFormulario[0].cd_nacion,
        cd_agrup_prof : this.dadosFormulario[0].cd_agrup_prof,
        cd_profis :     this.dadosFormulario[0].cd_profis,
        cd_categ :      this.dadosFormulario[0].cd_categ,
        loc_trab :      this.dadosFormulario[0].loc_trab
    })

    });


initializeForm()
        {
            this.myForm = new FormGroup({ 
                nome :          new FormControl(),
                dt_nasc :       new FormControl(),
                sexo :          new FormControl(),
                cd_nacion :     new FormControl(),
                cd_agrup_prof : new FormControl(),
                cd_profis :     new FormControl(),
                cd_categ :      new FormControl(),
                loc_trab :      new FormControl() 
        }
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! It was precisely what i needed!
Many thanks :)

Comment: Glad I could Help:)

Answer (score 2):

Your `this.dadosFormulario` will be null on onNgOnit(), that's why you are not seeing any value in the form..

You need to use patchValue to update form once you get data from your `funcionService`